CQRS Application-Commands and Transactions
I have a simple use-case: Sync a product from a remote system into the local application.
An excerpt of the buildingblocks implemented:

SyncProductCommand + associated SyncProductCommandHandler (wrapped in a transaction, because it's suggested by clean architecture and makes sense too)
RemoteProductRepositoryInterface (Domain) + RemoteProductRepository (Infrastructure)

The RemoteProductRepository fetches the RemoteProduct via REST-Interface from the remote system. Authenticating using OAuth token (with refresh token). The Repo (in detail an abstracted service / client) decides if the token has to be refreshed. If yes, it will refresh the token with the refresh-token, and saves both (new token and new refresh-token) to the database.
The flow would be something like that (in a very simplified representation):
SyncProductCommandHandler {
  handle(productId) {
    try {
      con.beginTransaction();
      remoteProduct = remoteProductRepository.get(productId); // this will maybe refresh the token and save it to the database too

      someService.createOrUpdateLocalProduct(remoteProduct); // will throw an exception     

      con.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // this not only rollbacks the changes made to the local product
      // it will also rollback updates (in the local db) to the token and refresh-token. but clearly not remotely.
      con.rollback();
    }
  }
}

You can imagine what the problem is... a rollback will also throw away my new oAuth-Token and refreshToken which means that I can no longer connect.

Clean architecture suggests that every application-command should be in one transaction. Which makes totally sense. Should i break this "law" in that case?
should i take the opportunity to refresh the token away from the RemoteProductRepository and create a dedicated command RefreshTokenCommand + handler? Doesn't look good to me, because i create a use-case for a technical detail...
create a dedicated connection and transaction only for storing tokens, so that a rollback will not affect this?

I think the problem basically exists because there is no rollback for refreshToken.

The refresh token is a technical detail of the RemoteProductRepository, because the client that this repository uses to retrieve the products from a remote service must handle the tokens. There is no need to create a separate command for the token update.
So the RemoteProductRepository itself updates the token when needed and saves it to the database in an own transaction. The refresh token does not need to be consistent in any way with the product, so there is no need to do it in the same transaction. At the moment you save the token in the same database as your domain data, but the token storage might change in the future, e.g. a distributed cache.
If your software runs in a multithreaded environment you should also keep in mind that multiple threads can refresh a token in parallel and might need to be synchronized.

I agree with you on everything. Regarding the multithreaded environment: this is already the case. We intercept this with redis-locks.
And as you pointed out... there should not be a separated command for refreshing tokens (because it's a technical detail, not an use-case).
but it's legacy-software, the token is stored in the same database, using the same connection,... so you describe the perfect world while I have do deal in a real one ;-)
